# Размещение елементов по кругу блока

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

подскажите пожалуйста как сделать вот такую вот штукую.
Не могу добавить полоски возле блоков(пометил стрелочками)
[image: полоски]

```
    <div class="parthners_wrapper">
    <div class="parthners_right" id="parthners_right">
        <div class="parthners_list" id="parthners_list">
            <div class="parthners_item"> </div>
            <div class="parthners_item"> </div>
            <div class="parthners_item"> </div>
            <div class="parthners_item"> </div>
            <div class="parthners_item"> </div>
            <div class="parthners_item"> </div>
            <div class="parthners_item"> </div>
            <div class="parthners_item"> </div>
            <div class="parthners_item"> </div>
            <div class="parthners_item"> </div>
            <div class="parthners_item"> </div>
        </div>
        <svg class="circle_one" width="692" height="730" viewBox="0 0 692 730" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M615.296 387.373C615.296 541.071 490.571 665.668 336.714 665.668C182.857 665.668 58.1313 541.071 58.1313 387.373C58.1313 233.675 182.857 109.078 336.714 109.078C490.571 109.078 615.296 233.675 615.296 387.373ZM66.4572 387.373C66.4572 536.478 187.455 657.351 336.714 657.351C485.972 657.351 606.97 536.478 606.97 387.373C606.97 238.269 485.972 117.396 336.714 117.396C187.455 117.396 66.4572 238.269 66.4572 387.373Z" fill="#2D9CDB" fill-opacity="0.4" />
            <path d="M583.708 282.296C584.976 284.954 588.159 286.082 590.817 284.814C593.476 283.546 594.603 280.363 593.335 277.704C592.067 275.046 588.884 273.918 586.226 275.186C583.567 276.454 582.44 279.637 583.708 282.296ZM588.952 280.903L650.23 251.678L649.369 249.872L588.091 279.097L588.952 280.903Z" fill="#3CA1EA" />
            <path d="M483.238 162.075C485.489 163.975 488.853 163.691 490.754 161.44C492.654 159.19 492.369 155.825 490.119 153.925C487.868 152.025 484.503 152.309 482.603 154.56C480.703 156.81 480.987 160.175 483.238 162.075ZM487.442 158.645L537.408 99.4579L535.88 98.1678L485.914 157.355L487.442 158.645Z" fill="#3CA1EA" />
            <path d="M603.644 424.879C603.577 427.824 605.91 430.265 608.854 430.332C611.799 430.399 614.241 428.066 614.308 425.121C614.374 422.176 612.042 419.735 609.097 419.668C606.152 419.601 603.711 421.934 603.644 424.879ZM608.953 426L691.914 427.885L691.96 425.886L608.998 424L608.953 426Z" fill="#3CA1EA" />
            <path d="M542.165 560.928C540.469 563.336 541.046 566.663 543.454 568.36C545.862 570.056 549.189 569.48 550.885 567.072C552.582 564.664 552.005 561.337 549.597 559.64C547.189 557.944 543.862 558.52 542.165 560.928ZM545.949 564.817L628.911 623.268L630.063 621.633L547.101 563.183L545.949 564.817Z" fill="#3CA1EA" />
            <path d="M421.258 642.959C418.474 643.922 416.997 646.959 417.959 649.742C418.922 652.526 421.959 654.003 424.742 653.041C427.526 652.078 429.003 649.041 428.041 646.258C427.078 643.474 424.041 641.997 421.258 642.959ZM422.055 648.327L450.055 729.327L451.945 728.673L423.945 647.673L422.055 648.327Z" fill="#3CA1EA" />
            <path d="M125.913 553.561C124.013 551.309 120.648 551.024 118.397 552.924C116.146 554.823 115.861 558.188 117.76 560.439C119.66 562.691 123.025 562.976 125.276 561.076C127.527 559.177 127.812 555.812 125.913 553.561ZM121.192 556.236L60.8559 607.144L62.1456 608.673L122.481 557.764L121.192 556.236Z" fill="#3CA1EA" />
            <path d="M251.603 642.913C248.793 642.028 245.798 643.588 244.913 646.397C244.028 649.207 245.588 652.202 248.397 653.087C251.207 653.972 254.202 652.412 255.087 649.603C255.972 646.793 254.412 643.798 251.603 642.913ZM249.046 647.699L226.046 720.699L227.954 721.301L250.954 648.301L249.046 647.699Z" fill="#3CA1EA" />
            <path d="M68.7445 424.761C68.6127 421.819 66.1205 419.54 63.1779 419.672C60.2354 419.804 57.9568 422.296 58.0885 425.239C58.2203 428.181 60.7125 430.46 63.6551 430.328C66.5976 430.196 68.8763 427.704 68.7445 424.761ZM63.3718 424.001L0.207875 426.829L0.297338 428.827L63.4612 425.999L63.3718 424.001Z" fill="#3CA1EA" />
            <path d="M87.4285 282.191C88.6385 279.505 87.4423 276.347 84.7568 275.137C82.0712 273.927 78.9133 275.124 77.7033 277.809C76.4934 280.495 77.6896 283.653 80.3751 284.863C83.0606 286.073 86.2185 284.876 87.4285 282.191ZM82.9767 279.088L5.93228 244.376L5.11071 246.199L82.1551 280.912L82.9767 279.088Z" fill="#3CA1EA" />
            <path d="M187.024 162.393C189.451 160.722 190.063 157.402 188.393 154.976C186.722 152.549 183.402 151.937 180.976 153.607C178.549 155.278 177.937 158.598 179.607 161.024C181.278 163.451 184.598 164.063 187.024 162.393ZM184.824 157.433L131.044 79.3213L129.396 80.4555L183.176 158.567L184.824 157.433Z" fill="#3CA1EA" />
            <path d="M339.048 118.333C341.993 118.307 344.359 115.898 344.333 112.952C344.307 110.007 341.898 107.641 338.952 107.667C336.007 107.693 333.641 110.102 333.667 113.048C333.693 115.993 336.102 118.359 339.048 118.333ZM340 112.991L339 0.991076L337 1.00893L338 113.009L340 112.991Z" fill="#3CA1EA" /> </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.parthners_right{
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 1150px;
    height: 1150px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.parthners_list{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
}
.parthners_wrapper{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.parthners_item{
    position: absolute;
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color:purple;
}
.circle_one{
    position: absolute;
    top: 48%;
    left: 51%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);  
}
```

Js

```
var theta = [];

var setup = function (n, r, id) {
    var main = document.getElementById("parthners_right");
    var mainHeight = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(main).height.slice(0, -2));
    console.log(mainHeight);
    var circleArray = document.getElementsByClassName('parthners_item');

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        circleArray[i].posx = Math.round(r * (Math.cos(theta[i]))) + 'px';
        circleArray[i].posy = Math.round(r * (Math.sin(theta[i]))) + 'px';
        circleArray[i].style.position = "absolute";
        circleArray[i].style.top = ((mainHeight / 2) - parseInt(circleArray[i].posy.slice(0, -2))) + 'px';
        circleArray[i].style.left = ((mainHeight/ 2 ) + parseInt(circleArray[i].posx.slice(0, -2))) + 'px';
    }
};

var generate = function(n, r, id) {
    var frags = 360 / n;
    for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        theta.push((frags / 180) * i * Math.PI);
    }
    setup(n, r, id)
}
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('parthners_item').length;
var main = document.getElementById("parthners_right");
var mainHeight = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(main).height.slice(0, -2));
var rad = mainHeight / 2;
generate(items, 420, 'main');
```

Пример кода - https://jsfiddle.net/barmaleyko/6yq401b5/1/

Comment: А на svg нарисовать? Проще же и ни какого js вообще не надо

Comment: `<hr/>` запихиваешь в `inline-block` контейнер и `rotate(33)` его, точки на окружности - контейнер с `border-radius: 50%;` в том же контейнере, ну а дабы точка вращения была удобная(в центре шара), padding или margin на одну сторону.

Comment: @Monkey Mutant элементы добавляются из админки. нужно разбивать круг на колличество елементов которое есть в базе. просто свг не получится

Comment: @puffleeck спасибо, попробую

Comment: Получится, просто поверьте